# Do we need HTTPS website to implement google app indexing?

Tags: android, android-app-indexing

I am planning to do app indexing and deep linking for my app. To link my website with the app, is the site required to be an HTTPS site?

In official Android documentation, it is mentioned that we need to have digital Asset JSON file in the website.

https://domain[:optional_port]/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Text from documentation:

> The system verifies the JSON file via the encrypted HTTPS protocol.
>   Make sure that your hosted file is accessible over an HTTPS
>   connection, regardless of whether your app's intent filter includes
>   https.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You do need to have a website for verified app links, but not necessarily for basic App Indexing. Of course, it's smoother for the user if you do.

You might give the free [Branch.io](https://branch.io) service a look *(full disclosure: I'm on the team)*. We can help handle all of your deep links, and you get Google App Indexing as a extra side benefit.